# File action popup url navingates inside an iframe in the popup

Tags: box-api

We have implemented a file action application similar to 'Send with Gmail', but the behaviour in our case appears to be different than how 'Send with Gmail' works.

In our case, the client callback URL is opened inside an iframe called 'service_iframe' in the popup window. As a result out app is unable to close the popup using window.close.

In the case of 'Send with Gmail', their URL shows up in the popup's address bar, which means there is no iframe involved, so window.close will work for them.

Any suggestions on what we could do to close this popup from our app at the end of our workflow?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional `redirect_to_box` parameter that you can have sent over from Box that when used, will call some JS on the iframe to close the window:

http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923961/BoxPlatformBoxParameters